# Does newLISP use garbage collection?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, lisp, newlisp

[This page](http://www.newlisp.org/MemoryManagement.html) has been quite confusing for me.

It says:

> Memory management in newLISP does not rely on a garbage collection algorithm. Memory is not marked or reference-counted. Instead, a decision whether to delete a newly created memory object is made right after the memory object is created.
>
> newLISP follows a one reference only (ORO) rule. Every memory object not referenced by a symbol is obsolete once newLISP reaches a higher evaluation level during expression evaluation. Objects in newLISP (excluding symbols and contexts) are passed by value copy to other user-defined functions. As a result, each newLISP object only requires one reference.

Further down, I see:

> All lists, arrays and strings are passed in and out of built-in functions by reference.

I can't make sense of these two.

How can newLISP "not rely on a garbage collection algorithm", and yet pass things by reference?
For example, what would it do in the case of circular references?!

Is it even *possible* for a LISP to not use garbage collection, without making performance go down the drain? (I assume you could always pass things by value, or you could always perform a full-heap scan whenever you think it might be necessary, but then it seems to me like that would insanely hurt your performance.)
If so, how would it deal with circular references? If not, what do they mean?

Comment: I read that as 'we pass copies to all function *except* built-in(!) function, they (and only they) get references".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps reading http://www.newlisp.org/ExpressionEvaluation.html helps understanding the http://www.newlisp.org/MemoryManagement.html paper better. Regarding circular references: they do not exist in newLISP, there is no way to create them. The performance question is addressed in a sub chapter of that memory management paper and here: http://www.newlisp.org/benchmarks/

May be working and experimenting with newLISP - i.e. trying to create a circular reference - will clear up most of the questions.

Comment: Mind blown! So not all LISPs have circular references?! Did not see that one coming. :) +1 definitely deserves lots of upvotes. Thanks!